# Passing parameters to AppleScript causes error

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript file that I'm passing two values to and it is giving me this error:

```
execution error: {"file2"} doesn’t match the parameters {fileName, fileName2} for run. (-1721)
```

Here is the AppleScript:

```
on run {fileName, fileName2}

    set output to fileName & "|" & fileName2

end run
```

**UPDATE:**
On further testing if I add more parameters it seems to work. Is there an arguments array or parameters array that I can use instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your handlers requires two parameters and you are only passing one. Post your handler call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
on run argv
    repeat with aParameter in argv
        display dialog aParameter as string
    end repeat
end run
```

The `on run`-argument (here called **argv**) is an Applescript list that contains the parameters.

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Is there a way to get the first and second parameter similar to how JavaScript works, such as argv[0] and argv[1]?

Comment: Try `first item of argv`and `second item of argv` etc.

Comment: Or you use `on run {fileName, fileName2}` but then you have to give exactly the given amount of parameters to your handler!